# Clothing data error “Graph is linked to external private object ClothingAssetCommon”

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I’m having a weird problem when it comes to animations for clothing and hair on some characters. If I’m duplicating the skeletal mesh that has clothing data, and save it, it works fine, but if I remove the data, save it, and then when I’m trying to add it back, I’m getting this error (on some, not all), as example Shimbi Jade:

```
Can't save ./../../../..//ParagonShinbi/Characters/Heroes/Shinbi/Skins/Tier_1/Shinbi_Jade/Meshes/ShinbiJade.uasset:
Graph is linked to external private object ClothingAssetCommon 
//ParagonShinbi/Characters/Heroes/Shinbi/Skins/Tier_1/Shinbi_Jade/Meshes/ShinbiJadeOriginal.ShinbiJadeOriginal:Mudang_Apex_geo_hair_LOD0 (ClothConfigs)
```

Do I need to make the data for clothing public? If so, how? If not, what else do I have to do?